# Bootstrap textarea focus not responding to CSS change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've changed the focus border glow for inputs using the following CSS:

```
textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="datetime"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="month"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="week"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="color"]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {
    border-width:2px;
    border-color: #BD2525;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 0px rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

But although this works great for a single line input:
[image]

It doesn't work for the textarea:
[image]

At a bit of a loss why it's not responding to the change. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting it as a new rule didn't work. But adding important as well as a new rule did:

```
textarea:focus {    
    border-width:2px  !important;
    border-color: #BD2525 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 0px rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.6)  !important;
    outline: 0 none  !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a new rule

```
textarea:focus { background: pink; }
```